# React native ipa file generate with ad hoc wont work ios 13 real device

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

Hi my react native version is 59.1, Xcode version 10.3 and I use ad hoc and take out ipa my app, will work iPhone 6 (IOS 12.) but iPhone 8 (13.1.3) wont install my ipa file gives warning (app is wont installing, please try again) Is the reason my Xcode version or something like that, anything idea, thanks for helping

Comment: Could you provide more details (screenshot, error msg, etc), it's difficult to help without knowing the exact error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you specify this when you create IPA files.

[image]

Comment: Yes ipa is work with iphone 6 and your image link wont open